# DNS Failover to maintenance page on AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Hello I host a maintenance page on Cloudfront, that redirects to a S3 static website. The alternate domain name is *.domain.fr. I have two records on Route 53, one with *.domain.fr with cname with the domain of my elastic beanstalk application (that doesnt use a load balancer), a TTL of 5 s, primary failover, and a healthcheck on the Elastic IP of the EC2 instance on /index.html (HTTP). I have a second record set with *.domain.fr with cname on the domain name of my cloudfront distribution, with failover secondary and associated with the same health check. But when i redply on elastic beanstalk and my application is not available, the maintenance page is not displayed, even after several minutes, why ?

So I made it work, i used TCP instead of HTTP in health check, with 10 seconds. But now i would like that when we type *.domain.fr/connexion, it redirects to the cloudfront distribution, right now i have access denied, how can i achieve that ?

Comment: DNS TTL is not an effective failover tool at the individual user level, because of browser behavior.  Closing all your browser windows and *then* checking the site again may show the desired result.

Comment: What is displayed? Does your S3 bucket name match exactly the domain name?